# How to turn 2d array out of 1d one?

Tags: c, memory-management

To access any element I use `*(Ptr + i)`.

Is there any way to put 2D array into the allocated memory in order to access any element using `array[i][j]`?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int *Ptr;

   Ptr = malloc(M*N*sizeof(int));

   for (i = 0; i <= M * N; i++)
      *(Ptr + i) = 1 + rand()%10;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int * foo = malloc(rows * columns * sizeof(int));  int bar = foo[i][j];`

Comment: ` for (i = 0; i < M * N; i++)
      Ptr[i] = 1 + rand()%10;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sample

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 4
#define M 3

int main()
{
    int *Ptr;
    int (*p)[M];
    int i,j;

    Ptr = malloc(M*N*sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < M * N; i++){
        *(Ptr + i) = 1 + rand()%10;
//      printf("%d ", Ptr[i]);
    }
//  printf("\n");

    p=(int (*)[M])Ptr;//p[N][M]
    for(i = 0; i < N ;++i){
        for(j = 0; j < M;++j)
            printf("%d ", p[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Genuine.Zealot pointer p is pointer to size M of int array (top address). ex) p point array[0..SIZE-1] , (p + 1) point second array (array[0..SIZE-1](<-first array),array[0..SIZE](<- second array)), means point to (top address) p[1][0 of 0..SIZE-1].

Comment: @BLUEPIXY... `p=(int (*)[M])Ptr;` does this line signify casting? or reinterpreting? I am still confused....

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int** theArray;  
theArray = (int**) malloc(M*sizeof(int*));  

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        theArray[i] = (int*) malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    }
```

Sample:

```
int M = 5;
int N = 5;

int** theArray = (int**) malloc(M*sizeof(int*));  

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        theArray[i] = (int*) malloc(N*sizeof(int));

        for(int j = 0 ; j < N; j++)
        {
            theArray[i][j] = i+j;
            printf("%d ", theArray[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < M; k++)
    {  
       free(theArray[k]);  
    }
    free(theArray);
```

Comment: Okay, maybe I got the question wrong. But you should atleast comment why did you minus the answer

Comment: You're creating an array of pointers.  The OP wants to access the memory as `array[i][j]`, which your solution doesn't allow.

Comment: I believe my snippet allows to acces it like this

Comment: In order to access `theArray[i][j]` in any useful way the array must be contiguous memory.  Yours is not.

Comment: What do you mean by "any useful way"? My array works like normal 2d array. If author wanted a 2d array in contiguous memory he should've stated it.

Comment: Added sample. Works like a charm. Or am I solving wrong problem?

Comment: Yes, it destroys your array of pointers quite well.  Try adding another loop at the end to free your mallocs and see what happens.

Comment: Added destruction loop to the sample. Still works. Did you expect access violation? I'm not trying to be picky, I'm really interested in what's wrong with that code.

Comment: When you do array indexing such as `theArray[i][j]`, that calculates an offset from `theArray[0][0]` using the expression `theArray + (i * M) + j`.  But for any value of `i` greater than 1 or any value of `j` greater than 5, you are indexing beyond the bounds of `theArray`.  The fact that it happened to work on your machine is pure luck.  It does not work on mine.  The only way your code would work reliably is to do only a single `malloc` and allocate `M*sizeof(int) + N * sizeof(int)` bytes.  That will give you the contiguous chunk of memory you need to treat it as a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Hm. I do not get why it gotta be contiguous memory. I thought that it is common practice to allocate 2-dimensional dynamic array: you allocate 1-dimensional array of pointers and for each value you allocate another 1-dimensional array. In fact, as far as I know multidimensional non-dynamic arrays in C are made exact same way, aren't they? Moreover, I did google it and didn't find anything that pointed out such a problem and every example of dynamic n-dimensional arrays are pretty much the same as my snippet. I'm gonna start a new question about this, so we don't make this comment feed a chat.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733642/multidimensional-arrays-in-c    - If anyone interested

Comment: @CareyGregory With the type `int**`, accessing `theArray[i][j]` reads the `int*` stored at `theArray[i]`, adds `j` to that, and reads the `int` located there. It's not what is considered a multidimensional array in C, but the code works well (as usual, if all indices are valid).