# Multidimensional arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, multidimensional-array

It is related to comments for my answer in this question: [How to turn 2d array out of 1d one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15731383/how-to-turn-2d-array-out-of-1d-one)

So, consider this snippet:

```
int M = 5;
int N = 5;

int** theArray = (int**) malloc(M*sizeof(int*));  

for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
    theArray[i] = (int*) malloc(N*sizeof(int));

    for(int j = 0 ; j < N; j++)
    {
        theArray[i][j] = i+j;
        printf("%d ", theArray[i][j]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

for (int k = 0; k < M; k++)
{  
   free(theArray[k]);  
}
free(theArray);
```

I gotta say that it works perfectly fine on my machine, but I was told in comments that it is pure luck and it is wrong way to declare 2-dimensional array, that memory should be allocated with only 1 malloc to get contiguous memory.

I'm genuinely perplexed, because I thought that non-dynamic multidimensional arrays in C works exactly the same way: they are basically an array of pointers, where each value is an array.

The question is, is it right (portable, common practice etc) way to do this? Did I miss something on this topic? I mean, I really don't see any problem with this code.

EDIT:

I got the answer which I finally understood from comments by WhozCraig and Daniel Fischer. My main mistake was that I assumed that arrays and pointers are more alike than they really are.

Main reason is row-major order in which actual multidimensional arrays are stored in linear memory (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order). And to understand practical difference between real multidimensional arrays and my snipppet I suggest reading this article (it made nice clarification on this topic for me and provdes easy to understand examples):

Part 1: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c/

Part 2: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/04/06/pointers-vs-arrays-in-c-part-2d/

Comment: You're premise that non-dynamic multi-dimensonal arrays are synonymous with pointers to pointers to data is entirely NOT correct. That said, your code is fine, so long as `theArray`is never passed to a function declared to accept a parameter similar to `int ar[][N]`. They are definitely *not* the same. There are several **outstanding** posts that discuss multi-dimension array work in C/C++. I will try and hunt them down, but suggest you do the same. Some of them are *amazing* in their ascii-art visuals =P

Comment: What WhozCraig said. Your code is fine, but what you allocate is not a multidimensional array.

Comment: So, the point is that code is correct, but technically it is multidimensional array only as "interface" but it's not really multidimensional array, right? Thanks for the answers, gonna go read something like pointers vs arrays, seems like my knowledge on this topic is wrong :)

Comment: The first article I assume was old-news to you. But the second does a pretty good job of spelling out how you can mimic a multi-dimension array in C using a pointer-to-pointer. Note that the one thing the `int**` approach *does* offer that true-multi-dimension arrays do not is *variable row width*. Not all rows have to be the same width using code like yours (obviously you better know what you're doing in that regard). Also, though that article it only briefly touches on it at the end, `int (*ar)[N]` is also common and I suggest writing some code to see how they work. It can be educational.

Answer (score 0):

Compare this code:

```
int array[10][10];

for (int i = 0; i < 10 * 10; i++) {
   *((int *)array+i) = 0;
}
```

This is fine for a two dimensional array, as all of the memory is contiguous. With your version, you have a contiguous set of pointers, each of which could be pointing anywhere in memory.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that non-dynamically allocated array is contiguous in memory. The thing is that I was told, that my code is completely incorrect, which turned out to be false - it's just not technically a multidimensional array (maybe I got the commenter in linked question wrong, maybe he meant it). Got it from WhozCraig and Daniel Fischer comments on this question.

Comment: @StanMcGeek - your code is either correct or completely incorrect depending on what you want to do with it :) If you treated it as a multidimensional array, in many contexts you'd get a segfault, in others it'd be fine.